Unity - Forcing UI update after deleting an option from a dropdown
I'm building a custom dropdown menu where each item has a button to delete that option. It looks like this:

It's currently working almost as it should, the only problem is that the UI is not updated after I delete one of the items, which means already-deleted items are still shown and interactable until you close and reopen the dropdown. Here is my code:
public class DeletableDropdown : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler {

    public TMP_Dropdown dropdown; // Set in inspector

    public void RemoveOption(int index) {
        Debug.Log("Remove " + index + " - " + dropdown.options[index].text);
        dropdown.options.RemoveAt(index);
        LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(dropdown.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
    }

    // Add onClickListener to every button when the dropdown is clicked 
    // This is the earliest we can do this, since the items of the dropdown are not instantiated before
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData) {

        // Not sure why we need to start with -1. There seems to be an empty default element
        int i = -1;
        foreach (Transform child in dropdown.transform.Find("Dropdown List/Viewport/Content")) {
            int localIndex = i;
            child.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => RemoveOption(localIndex));
            i++;
        }     
    }
}

ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate doesn't seem to do anything. Any help is appreciated.

ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate is for Layout Groups that dynamically scale elements (such as HorizontalLayoutGroup), while TMP_Dropdown creates and positions its own child elements with the Show method.
You can try calling Hide then Show to force the dropdown to repopulate its options (which would drop focus and might flicker), or make your own dropdown class that handles the child elements on its own.
Related: Unity: Dynamically update Dropdown list when opened while not losing focus on InputField

Try to hide and show the dropdown again after removing an option:
dropdown.options.RemoveAt(index);
dropdown.Hide();
dropdown.Show();

